# How can I minimize the risk of mind control with magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, optimization, epic-tier, mind-control

We are playing a very overpowered game (which is perhaps at the level of rocket tag), but is a ton of fun. My character is a 17th-level [Zealot Barbarian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/barbarian#PathoftheZealot) (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 11) and I intend to take him to level 20.

In the game, we are hunting liches and twice now the character has been mind-controlled, much to the detriment of our group's cleric.

Because of the high-powered nature of the game, we are regularly confronted with save DCs of 24 (or higher). Unfortunately, my Barbarian's Wisdom save is only +2, so there's no way for me to make the save. Advantage on saves is not an issue, but there still needs to be a possibility for success for that to matter.

When we are expressly lich-hunting, we can prep and thus cast [*mind blank*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mind-blank), but sometimes we are the victims of attempted [Scry and Die style tactics](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?112056-Scry-and-Die-Tactics).

Our party consists of a Zealot Barbarian, Storm Sorcerer, Thief Rogue, Divination Wizard, Light Cleric, and a Shepherd Druid. We are all 17th level.

We have access to just about any magic item. Furthermore, our house rule means that my Barbarian's zealot revival feature extends to reincarnation spells. It should be noted that to simplify the maths associated with reincarnation, the new form loses the old racial features and gains the new ones, but we don't change the ability scores.

With that in mind, are there any magic items that provide persistent long-term protection against mind control or a means to provide static boosts to Wisdom saves? Alternative means to increasing the likelihood of making a DC24+ save vs. mind control with a +2 Wisdom save are also of interest (this includes suicide and trying to reincarnate as something with better odds).

Comment: What is Scry and Die? What type of Mind Control are you wanting protection from (specific items/spells?)

Comment: @NautArch any and all. Dominate Person and Monster are the most common threats from liches, but Suggestion/Mass Suggestion can also be an issue.

Comment: When you say you have access to pretty much any magic item does that include possible items from specific adventures?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I think you may need to split this up (but i'll let folks vote on that.) Items that prevent against Charm are different than items that prevent against being magically paralyzed.

Comment: @NautArch Paralysis is sometimes an issue, but something more practically mitigated within combat, I'm not as worried about it the way I am about mind control. The question is about mind control, not enchantment spells in general.

Comment: Preventing scrying and/or teleportation is also a separate issue. I think you've got at last four possible questions here (how can I prevent either being scryed, prevent teleportation to the party, prevent charm effects, prevent against spells like Hold/Dominate Person in either effect or instance.)

Comment: @NautArch I'm not bothered by the Scry and Die. It is an issue from an in-game perspective, but our table is fine with it, so it's not an issue. We're having fun making convoluted plans to keep liches off our tails while we try and sneak up on them. Right now we're developing some crazy make a Demiplane with a private sanctum, and non-detection for good measure. I'm just interested in keeping them from having guaranteed mind control on the party barbarian.

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest paring down your question to just that - but I think you do need to be clearer in what specific spells you are looking to make sure they can't counteract.

Comment: @Sdjz as long as you have a citation for me to refer my DM to, I think it would be allowed.

Comment: Does it have to be a magic item or are you ok with answers that just demonstrate tour ability to mitigate through the characters you have access to? (I'm thinking things like *dispel magic* / *counterspell* and portent if you can just get a little boost)

Comment: Are you looking for Always-on protection or for things that could help acutely in a specific situation if prepared?

Comment: @NautArch Anything that provides a means for a character with a +2 Wisdom save to have a chance to make a DC24 save versus mind control is worth consideration.

Comment: Okay - but FYI, while Wisdom is the prevailing save against Enchantment spells, there are still some that use CHA, INT and even one for CON (although a lot of those are damage type spells and not Command/Control.) This is why I was hoping you could narrow down what you wanted protection from rather than a generic *mind control*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a trip to Ravenloft.

At your party's level it should be no trouble at all to obtain... (warning: Curse of Strahd spoilers)

> The Icon of Ravenloft (Curse of Strahd p.222) . One of the properties of this item states that: "While within 30 feet of the icon, a creature is under the effect of a protection from evil and good spell against fiends and undead."

Since you are fighting Liches this should completely suit your needs. Naturally, this will not help if

> The liches are using minions that are not undead or fiends

Answer (score 10):

#### Defense against being charmed/controlled/dominated

A **[Cloak of Protection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/cloak-of-protection)** *(DMG p. 159, uncommon, attunement)* gives +1 to AC and saves. So does a **[Ring of Protection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-protection)** *(DMG p. 191, rare, attunement)*.  A **[Stone of Good Luck](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/stone-of-good-luck-luckstone)** *(DMG p. 205, uncommon, attunement)* increases saves and abilites by +1.

A **[Ring of Spell Turning](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-turning)** *(DMG p. 193, legendary, attunement)* can reflect a spell if you roll a 20 on your save.

A **[Scarab of Protection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/scarab-of-protection)** *(DMG p. 199, legendary, attunement)* gives you advantage on saving throws vs some spells/effects, but also lets you spend a charge to turn a fail vs undead spell/effect into a success.  This might not apply to non-necromancy spells though.

**[Staff of Charming](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-charming)** *(DMG p. 201, rare, attunement by full caster)* can let you turn a failed save vs enchantment into a success once a day, but you would need to multiclass to attune to it.  Similarly, the **[Staff of the Magi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-the-magi)** *(DMG p. 203, legendary, attunement by a full arcane caster)* would let you absorb some spells. This staff can also cast **Protection from Evil** for you.

These options are good options too, but are not items. Other readers may find them helpful though.

The **[Protection from Evil and Good](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/protection-from-evil-and-good)** spell *(PHB p. 270, 1st-level spell, 10 min, concentration)* will prevent you from being charmed or possessed by an evil creature.  It would not be unusual for a holy artifact to grant such protection to its wielder.  **Maybe you could seek out a magic item which has Protection from Evil as a constant effect.**

The **[Bless](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bless)** spell *(PHB 219, 1st-level spell, 1 min, concentration)* will give the targets +1d4 on attacks and saves.

The **[Resilient](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/resilient)** feat *(PHB p. 168)* will allow you to become proficient in a save (and add +1 to that ability).  That should give you +6 or +7 (if your Wisdom score was odd) to your save.

#### Defense against other harmful effects

An **[Amulet of Proof Against Detection and Location](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/amulet-of-proof-against-detection-and-location)** *(DMG p. 150, uncommon, attunement)* will prevent scrying.

A **[Ring of Free Action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-free-action)** *(DMG 191, rare, attunement)* will prevent you from being paralyzed (or restrained or having your speed set to 0).

Comment: Looks like we were editing at the same time :) Regarding the formatting of the 2 spell names, I was just following WotC's own convention of typing them in lowercase with italics.

Comment: You may also want to include a Ring of Free Action in that list as it may negate some mind control effects.

Comment: @V2Blast - I was sure you had your reasons, but since everything else in here is capitalized (as well as in the PHB), I prefer that style.  Thanks for the linking.